# Find Duplicate In MongoDB While Comparing Some Field In those Duplicate Items

Tags: mongodb, duplicates, aggregator

I Have a DB

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "email": "amrit@gmail.com",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "status": "INACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "email": "tut@gmail.com",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "email": "amrit@gmail.com",
    "status": "INACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "email": "tut@gmail.com",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
  },
  {
    "_id": 6,
    "email": "cat@gmail.com",
    "status": "ACTIVE"
  },
  
]
```

Now I want to find the item according to emails, which have status as both ACTIVE and INACTIVE.
I have written the query to find duplicates like this.

```
db.getCollection(‘employees’).aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: {email: “$email”},
        uniqueIds: {$addToSet: “$_id”},
        count: {$sum: 1}
        }
    },
    {$match: {
        count: {“$gt”: 1}
        }
    }
], {allowDiskUse:true });
```

This return both tut@gmail.com and amrit@gmail.com but I only want amrit@gmail.com as it as both ACTIVE and INACTIVE in db.
Result should look like

```
{
    "_id": {
      "email": "amrit@gmail.com"
    },
    "uniqueIds": [
      4,
      1
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below query.

```
db.getCollection("employees").aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        email: "$email"
      },
      uniqueIds: {
        $addToSet: "$_id"
      },
      status: {
        $addToSet: "$status"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      status: {
        "$all": [
          "ACTIVE",
          "INACTIVE"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      status: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here is [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ku-uRbf90O2) for you.